# Make a table fully responsive

Tags: html, css

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>A</td>
        <td>B</td>
        <td>C</td>
        <td>D</td>
    <tr>
</table>
```

How to make a table fully responsive?

Comment: what do you mean by fully responsive. Add some css/style and if you are getting issue then come with issue.

Answer (score 3):

The best way to make a table fully responsive is to use the bootstrap. Bootstrap is the most popular HTML, CSS, and JS framework for developing responsive, mobile first projects on the web.

[Download](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#download) the bootstrap and include its stylesheet

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

Then simply use the bootstrap table class..

```
 <table class="table">
<thead>
  <tr>
    <th>Firstname</th>
    <th>Lastname</th>
    <th>Email</th>
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <td>John</td>
    <td>Doe</td>
    <td>john@example.com</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Mary</td>
    <td>Moe</td>
    <td>mary@example.com</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>July</td>
    <td>Dooley</td>
    <td>july@example.com</td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

Your table will be fully responsive for all devices.. But don't forget to use the viewport..

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

You can view demo on [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_tables.asp)  and get bootstrap [here](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#panels-tables)